# Multi-client socket programming zombie processes

Tags: c, sockets, fork, zombie-process

I wish to achieve multi-client connectivity to a server to transfer some data using `fork()` system call. Using the command `ps -a`. I found that after my client program terminates, the child process created in the server to handle the data transfer becomes a zombie process (shows `<defunct>` against the process). I am aware that a `wait()` in the parent process may solve the problem, but I need the while loop in the parent process running continuously to accept incoming client connections and cannot afford to wait for the child process to end. Please help me on how could I solve the zombie process problem. My server program is as follows:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    int sock = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    int addrlen = sizeof(addr);
    char buffer[1024] = {0};

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    addr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    addr.sin_port = htons(2222);
    bind(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

    listen(sock,5);
    while(1)
    {
        int conn = accept(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, (socklen_t *)&addrlen);
        int pid = fork();
        if(pid==0)
        {
            char buffer[1024] = {0};
            int readval = read(conn, buffer, 1024);
            printf("%s\n",buffer);
            break;
        }
        else if(pid < 0) printf("Process creation error");
    }

    close(conn);
    close(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

My client programs are as follows:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int sock = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    char msg[] = "Hello Server, this is Client 1";  

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    saddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_port = htons(2222);
    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr));

    send(sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
    sleep(20);

    close(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

and

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int sock = 0;
    struct sockaddr_in saddr;
    char msg[] = "Hello Server, this is Client 2";  

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    saddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    saddr.sin_port = htons(2222);
    connect(sock, (struct sockaddr *)&saddr, sizeof(saddr));

    send(sock, msg, strlen(msg), 0);
    sleep(20);

    close(sock);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two common ways to avoid zombies:

1) use a nonblocking wait in the main loop, for example waitpid(-1, ..., WNOHANG)

or

2) install a SIGCHLD handler. It's invoked asynchronously when a child exits, so just wait from there. You don't even have to write your own handler, as just doing signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN) should auto-reap zombies for you. Just beware that if you do that, the wait*() functions can't give you their exit codes.

Comment: waitpid(-1, &status, WUNTRACED | WCONTINUED);
worked for me